# Leaflet Popup with null values and unknown properties

Tags: null, leaflet, popup

When a user drag and drop a CSV point file into the Leaflet map, there is no way to see what kind of properties exist beforehand. So I need to find a solution, when user click a point on the map, only properties with values should be shown.

I been using below sample that works fine but only when the properties are known as shown. How can this be changed to show any properties with values but don't show properties with null or empty values?

```
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    
    var popupText = '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.typeId) ? 'Concept:\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.typeId: ''
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.branchId) ? '</b><br>BranchID:\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.blomId: '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.name) ? '</b><br>Name:\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.name: '';

    popupText += (feature.properties.streetName) ? '<br></b>StreetName:\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.streetName.toUpperCase(): '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.streetNumber) ? '\u00A0</b><b>' + feature.properties.streetNumber: '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.streetLetter) ? '\u00A0</b><b>' + feature.properties.streetLetter: '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.postalCode) ? '</b><br>PostalCode, City:\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.postalCode: '';
    
    popupText += (feature.properties.city) ? '</b>,\u00A0<b>' + feature.properties.city: '';
            

  layer.bindPopup(popupText, {
    closeButton: true,
    offset: L.point(0, -20)
  });
  layer.on('click', function() {
    layer.openPopup();
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all properties:

```
for(var prop in feature.properties){
   if(feature.properties[prop]){
      popupText += prop + ": "+feature.properties[prop]+"<br>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is one problem all values comes in one single line, need break line "/n" for each properties...

Comment: Changed ... Html uses `<br>`

Comment: youre fast, yes I did :), but the title is lost, need them as well not only values

Comment: Changed too. Would be nice if you accept the answer

Comment: Faster then lightning, thanks yes of course its accepted